# jquerymobile pageinit() page hidden?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
var $page = el.parents('div[data-role="page"]:visible');
```

Being called on `pageinit()` is showing null for me. Does anyone know the appropriate handler to  access elements height from JQM on? (As I need to run height() when the element is displayed)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I just found out that the actual issue here is that elements don't seem to have a height() until pageshow handler is called (which runs after pageinit)

so use that handler to run any events based on grabbing existing heights etc

Answer (score 2):

If you want a reference to the currently displayed page in jQuery Mobile there is the `$.mobile.activePage` property. It stores a jQuery object of the current page.

So to get the height of the current `<div data-role="page">` element you would do:

```
var the_height = $.mobile.activePage.height();
```

Or you could get the height of the `<div data-role="content">` section:

```
var the_height = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').height();
```

Here's a link to the page in the documentation about this (however there is almost no info for this property, you may still want to browse the page to see what jQuery Mobile has built-in): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: thanks for your answer was getting a bit annoyed with this lol. Seems like there a few areas in the JQM documentation which are a bit scarce!! They need a better demo for single page I think slightly more elaborate